# How to keep only one transaction per job execution?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

My `spring-batch` configuration contains a job with a number of steps. In one step I read messages from a `JMS` queue and in another step I write data to a database. *I would like the whole job executes in the same `JTA` transaction*

**The problems**

1. When I make the **reader** `@Transactional`, the `job` commits the transaction after the **reader** receives all the messages from the `JMS` queue and then the `job` starts a new transaction for the **writer**. It does not allow me to keep single transaction per job execution;
2. When I make the **job launcher** `@Transactional` the job execution fails with

   `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).`

Apparently the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` class [adds additional adviser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/fa6286101568bb72ec5a7b7c91262d97d945ea1f/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java#L172) to check if there is an active transaction and if so the `adviser` throws the exception.

How can I fulfill the requirement? My only idea left is to resort in some sort of a `AOP` configuration approach (e.g. to add an intecepter on [AbstractJob#execute](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/fa6286101568bb72ec5a7b7c91262d97d945ea1f/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/AbstractJob.java#L291)).

I use `Atomikos` to manage `JTA` transactions. `JobRepository` has its own `DataSourceTransactionManager` instance with its own `DataSource`.

Comment: You cannot. Each step (or depending on your type of step chunk) runs in a transaction. That is also the whole point and idea of Spring Batch to make that possible and restart or continue a failed job. Looks like you have things in steps that shouldn't be different steps but rather a single step/chunk with a reader and writer.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thank you for you comment. I figured out why it did not work: I did not provide the `tasklet` with a valid `TransactionManager`, please, leave an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @zaratustra Good to see you solved your issue. I second the comment by M. Deinum, just wanted to add a note about the need to set the [readerIsTransactionalQueue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/SimpleStepBuilder.html#readerIsTransactionalQueue--) flag in this kind of setup instead of making the reader `@Transactional` (as you mentioned in your problem 1).